# RediretAction in MVC causes "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **contentController** like this :

```
 public class ContentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = obj.GetContentlist();
        return View(model);
    }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Content content)
        {
            obj.AddNewContent(content);
            obj.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","content");
        }
}
```

That as you can see contains **create action** .But in the last line ,when it is going to be executed **RedirectToAction("Index","content");** i got this error :

```
    HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
    The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

    Most likely causes:

    A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

Comment: What URL is routed to Content/Index?

Comment: No ,is routed to Content/  not index.

Comment: I changed it to RedirectToAction("Index"); but not working

Comment: Do you have a Content folder in the project? I bet you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default MVC template includes a "Content" folder.  Since you're redirecting to content/index and index is most likely the default action, you actually get redirected to /content -- which is the content directory rather than your controller.  If I were you I would choose another name for your controller to avoid the conflict.